# Multiple arrays into a session

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function receiving a stringified json object on post. For each time a checkbox is clicked, I want that data to be added to the array. For some reason when I click multiple checkboxes, it only stores the first data I clicked. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public function add_to_composer() {
    session_start();
    $result = "1"; // maybe return 1 if the cdo was added into the session array, and -1 if it was deleted? just an idea

    if(!isset($array))
    {
        $array = array($this->input->post()); 
        $_SESSION['composer'] = $array;
    }

    else if(isset($array)) {
        array_push($array, $this->input->post());
        $_SESSION['composer'] = $array;
    }

    //$_SESSION['rep1']= json_encode($this->input->post(), true);
    //array_push($_SESSION['composer'], $_SESSION['rep1']);

    // add the cdo to the session array, or else remove it
    var_dump($this->input->post());
}
```

Comment: I don't see in your code how `$array` is set, except for in that first condition, so that `else if` never gets executed. Perhaps you mean to use `$_SESSION['composer']` in your `isset( )` calls?

Comment: also, since you are doing the exact opposite condition between your `if` and `else if`, you don't need to do the `else if`, just do `else`

Answer (score 0):

What is `$array`? To me it looks like you want the following:

```
<?php

public function addToComposer() {
    session_start();
    $post = $this->input->post();
    if (!is_array($post)) {
        $post = array($post);
    }
    $_SESSION["composer"] = $post;
}

?>
```

Why? `$array` is a local (scope) variable and not initialized at the point you use it, therefor it's always *not an array* because it's not set at all.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your conditions are both redundant. `!isset($array)` will always be `true`, because `$array` is never set (i.e. assigned to). Which makes the existence of `else` redundant (and thus, the existence of the second condition, which BTW was redundant to begin with, being the exact opposite of the first one).

By eliminating the assignment to `$result`, which is never used, your function boils down to:

```
public function add_to_composer() {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['composer'] = array($this->input->post()); 

  //$_SESSION['rep1']= json_encode($this->input->post(), true);
  //array_push($_SESSION['composer'], $_SESSION['rep1']);

  // add the cdo to the session array, or else remove it
  var_dump($this->input->post());
}
```

> For some reason when I click multiple checkboxes, it only stores the
>   first data I clicked.

I think the above partially answers this concern as well: Since `$_SESSION['composer']` is being reassigned every time, previously stored data are overwritten. Only, *by the last post data*, not the first.

> ...I want that data to be added to the array.

This is something that, if my assumptions are correct, could be achieved with something along the lines of:

```
$_SESSION['composer'][]=$this->input->post();
```

I hope this helps clarifying things and provides you with a guide towards the right direction.